# How to store (read and write) JSON as custom field in Salesforce?

Tags: apex

Please,

What is the recommended way to have a field that can store JSON DATA (never larger than 20Kb)?

Would this affect CASE object performance in any significant way (20% or more performance hit)?

The data would not be parsed by Salesforce nor important to functions directly, so maybe a simple TEXTFIELD would be enough?

This JSON would be required by downstream systems that need to get extra information as part of the CASE. Example, the CASE request to transfer money from current account to account X with VALUE Y. For this case we would have a JSON stored like:

```
{
payload-version: 1.1
destination-account: 343434
currency: USD
amount: 1000000 --3 digits for cents
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In terms of capturing the data that you are going to use within the JSON, I'd actually recommend moving this to it's own object that is attached to the Case so that you can use a standard record creation screen or Flow to allow the end users to capture this information within the Salesforce UI. This also allows you to potentially capture multiple instances of the payload for a single Case record if that is ever required. You can then use this data to construct the payload that you need to send to your downstream system using Apex Defined Data Types when you make the callout to your downstream system using the JSON class methods.

If you need to store the actual JSON payload in Salesforce for audit purposes, I would recommend just using a Long Text Area field to store JSON content. You wouldn't have any performance impacts when interacting with records, and if required you could add this to the layout of the child object storing this data.  I would recommend you do some thorough analysis on the maximum size of the JSON payload you'd expect, and then add a generous buffer to this to ensure that you aren't going to hit field character limits in the future.

These might be some useful links if you haven't considered them already:

- [Considerations for Apex Defined Data Types](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_considerations_apex_data_type.htm&type=5)
- [JSON Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_System_Json.htm)

Comment: Makes sense! Another question would be, for the SF agent that is populating the CASE (creating it) he/she should see the fields:

Destination account
Amount

in the SF UI, so that they have a chance to provide that information (that will be stored as JSON).

As I am not from the SF world, would this be simple to implement in SF UI ?

Thanks

Comment: I will recommend creating an attachment record and work with it as you said its about 20KB and you have 32kb area there (in long text) . If you are very sure your application is scalable within that 10 KB limit use that field but just in case you need to track the changes then this approach (long text area) is not going to work

Comment: @jfbaro Salesforce works like a relational database it will store inside the platform case object reference is here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_case.htm

Comment: @jfbaro I've actually updated my answer based on that secondary question. As mentioned above, if you're wanting to have users capture those details you're better off capturing these as actual records so that you can leverage the native Salesforce UI, and then use those records to construct the payload you required.